# Объясните мне вложенные циклы в python

Tags: python, циклы, for

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print(i, j)
```

результат:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

Объясните мне как работает это код, прям в в деталях и простыми словами прошу!

Comment: А что мешает описание языка прочитать?

Comment: В каждом учебнике написано. Прям в деталях и простыми словами

Answer (score 2):

**`for`** - цикл. Одни и те же действия в нем выполняются по условию, заданному в скобках. В данном случае в скобках указана цифра **3**. Это означает, что цикл будет выполнен 3 раза, при этом каждый раз присваивая переменной, указанной после `for`, значение, заданное по условию.

---

В цикле `for i in range(3)` условие по умолчанию означает, что переменной `i` будет присвоено значение от **`0`** до **`3`** **(НЕ ВКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО)**. Таким образом, переменная `i` примет значения: `0`, `1`, `2`.

---

Однако есть еще один вложенный цикл, для переменной `j`. Здесь вложенность означает то, что при одном выполнении основного цикла, вложенный будет выполнен 3 раза. То есть, пока `i` будет равна `0`, переменная `j` успеет принять значения `0`, `1` и `2`. После чего выводит значение `i` и получившиеся значения `j`.

Так проходит первый круг цикла для переменой `i`. А поскольку всего их 3 и вложенный цикл тоже выполняется 3 раза - на экран будет выведено (3 ∙ 3) = 9 строк, где `i` принимает `0`, `1` и `2` по одному разу, а `j` по три раза.

Comment: Благодарю, просто! БЛАГОДАРЮ!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых объясню, что функция range(x)  возвращается объект "диапазон", если этой функции подаётся один аргумент, то такой объект будет выглядеть: 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., х - 1 соответственно i и j переменные-счетчики циклов for, которые принимают поочередно значения от 0 до 2.

1. Внешний цикл начинает выполнение своего тела и счётчик i  = 0, в теле этого цикла содержится ещё один цикл со счётчиком j, который также будет принимать значения от 0 до 2.
2. Начинается запуск внутреннего цикла и j = 0. 3. В теле внутреннего
   цикла выполняется вывод  текущих значений переменных-счетчиков .
   Внешний цикл перейдет на следующую итерацию, только тогда, когда
   полностью обработает внутренний цикл, т. е. пока j не станет равен
   2, потом i = 1 и внутренний цикл опять начинается с 0 до 2 и выводит
   значения этих счётчиков

Comment: Я запутался, я не понял :(

Answer (score 0):

Ох не знаю, но попытаюсь, в первом for i=0 и идёт дальше выполнение цикла, в котором встречается другой for и который будет выполняться, где по условию j переменная будет равняться 0 1 2, соответственно выведется 0 0, 0 1, 0 2. После чего в главном цикле for ничего не следует он выполняется заново с переменной i = 1, где уже дальше опять выполнять другой цикл for с переменной j равной 0 1 2, и выводится на экран 1 0, 1 1, 1 2 и т.д.